# XML-RPC Odoo - C # multiple search conditions with operator or

Tags: c#, odoo, xml-rpc

I want to do a search but I need to use the or operator

```
ids = models.execute_kw (db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'search', [[['name', '=', "jhon"] or ['name', '=', "wil"]]])
```

Can someone help me.

Comment: What does this have to do with XML-RPC or even XML?  Besides, this line won't even compile. Strings in C# use double quotes. Nor can you use naked square brackets

Answer (score 1):

The code above is not `C#` but seems like `Python`

The `OR` operator is written like this `|` and the new code will be  `ids = models.execute_kw (db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'search', [['|', ['name', '=', "jhon"], ['name', '=', "wil"]]])`

To learn more about Odoo search domains check these two links [search domains docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/orm.html#search-domains) - [Domain notation](http://christophe-simonis-at-tiny.blogspot.com/2008/08/new-new-domain-notation.html)

I don't have experience with `C#` but I did a quick research and here is a link to get you started `C#` [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33333185/xml-rpc-odoo-c-sharp-multiple-search-conditions). And for the domain here is an example

```
object[] do1 = new object[] { "name", "=", "jhon" };
object[] do2 = new object[] { "name", "=", "wil" };
object[] domain = new object[] { "|", do1 , do2};
```